# get count of list element( based upon click)?

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

PS: I am using [this Jquery plugin](http://pikachoose.com/versions/), although my question is not dependent on that.

```
    <div class="pikachoose">
        <ul id="pikame" class="jcarousel-skin-pika">
            <li><a href="http://www.pikachoose.com"><img src="../../10.jpg"/></a</li>
            <li><a href="http://www.pikachoose.com"><img src="../../20.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.pikachoose.com"><img src="../../30.jpg"/></a</li>
            <li><a href="http://www.pikachoose.com"><img src="../../40.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.pikachoose.com"><img src="../../50.jpg"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I want to get the index of "li" tag clicked.

```
  $("#pikame li").size();
```

will return me total number of "li". But i want to get index of that "li"

Like if image 40.jpg is clicked then i want to get 3(index starting from 0,1,2 so on...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().index());
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/zvkgv/

EDIT: Expanded example per comment request:

```
$('#pikame a').click(function(){
    $('#pikame2 li').eq($(this).parent().index()).find('img').trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

New Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/zvkgv/2/

Comment: a little more help, basically i want to trigger click for image of the Nth li ... If i know id of li then i can do $('#fc img').trigger('click'); but how to to the same thing if u know only index.

Comment: no, same html format but we just know nth li in a ul.. Basically i am managing two ul on the same page.. from one i need to find out index and in other i have to trigger the click event

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but you want `eq()` not `:nth-child`. nth-child starts on a 1-index. Check out the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/zvkgv/2/ -- Click on an image on the left list and it should trigger the click on the right list.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) on the #pikame element, then [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index) on the `li`:

```
$("#pikame").delegate("li", "click", function() {
    // $(this).index() is the index of the `li` clicked
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/iguxoy)

Though it really doesn't matter how you get to the `li` element; the key bit is once you're there, `index` with no arguments tells you its index amongst its siblings. Since `li` elements can only have `li` siblings, no need to give `index` a selector or anything.

Comment: @AlienWebguy a little more help, basically i want to trigger click for image of the Nth li ... If i know id of li then i can do $('#fc img').trigger('click'); but how to to the same thing if u know only index.